# Iterating a vector in reverse order with a range-for loop?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

I want to iterate a vector in reverse order , i know that i can do it easily  by below code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v(10);
    for(auto it=v.rbegin();it!=v.rend();it++)
        cout<<*it<<"";
}
```

For iterating in forward we can simply do by below code.

```
for(auto it:v)
  cout<<it<<" ";
```

Now task is ...

Is it possible to do reverse iterate similar to `for(auto it:v) cout<<it<<" "`. If YES then How?

Answer (score 7):

If you can use C++20, you can use the ranges library and thus [`std::ranges::reverse_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view):

```
vector<int> v(10);
std::ranges::reverse_view vReversed{v};

for(auto it : vReversed)
    cout<<it<<" ";
```

Comment: Beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write one on your own. Something like

```
template<class Source>
struct Reverse {
     Reverse(Source &&s): s(std::forward<Source>(s)) {}
     constexpr decltype(auto) begin() const { return std::rbegin(s); }
     constexpr decltype(auto end() const { return std::rend(s); }
private:
     S &&s;
};
```

Comment: Are you aware that `s` _is not_ a forwarding reference? You cannot construct `Reverese` with an lvalue vector ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/yAppFg)). Also, there are typos in your code. Please, try to compile and use it first before posting here.

Comment: @DanielLangr ... or simply admit that "something like" is not synonymous with "production-ready".